# Coefficient of $x^m$ in the expansion of $(1+x+x^2+x^3)^m$

Tags: combinatorics

I want to count the coefficient of $x^m$ in the expansion of $(1+x+x^2+x^3)^m$

---

we can think of this problem as count possible $m$ steps which consist of $0,1,2,3$ where the order matters and all step sum up to $m$.

First, I have to check how many ways to decompose $m$ into as a sum of $0,1,2,3$.

Second, with the given composition of first step, make them arranged in order.

---

How could one do the counting in the first process most easily and efficiently?

Comment: Your title and statement are not the same. Is the outer exponent $n$ or $m$?

Comment: @martycohen typo in title. edited

Answer (score 3):

Factorise $(1+x+x^2+x^3)=(1+x)(1+x^2)$ and binomially expand
\begin{eqnarray*}
[x^m]: \left( \sum_{i=0}^{m} \binom{m}{i} x^i \right) \left(\sum_{j=0}^{m} \binom{m}{j} x^{2j} \right) 
\end{eqnarray*}
So we require $i+2j=m$ giving 
\begin{eqnarray*}
 \sum_{j=0}^{ \left\lfloor \frac{m}{2} \right\rfloor } \binom{m}{j}  \binom{m}{m-2j}  
\end{eqnarray*}
It remains to be seen if this can be simplified further.
The first few terms are $1,3,10,31,101,\cdots$ and more details about this sequence can be found here https://oeis.org/search?q=1%2C3%2C10%2C31%2C101&language=english&go=Search

Comment: (+1): the factorization $(1+x)\left(1+x^2\right)$ works nicely here.

Comment: you guys are doing some beautiful things.. wow. thx for valuable link

Answer (score 2):

This is isomorphic to the problem of how many ways can you roll a total of $m$ on $m$ 4-sided dice (which are numbered from 0 to 3).

Which is, in turn, a "stars and bars" problem.  How many ways can we arrange $m$ stars into $m$ bins such that no bin holds 4 or more stars.

${2m-1\choose m-1} - {m\choose 1}{2m-5\choose m-1} + {m\choose2}{2m-9\choose m-1}\cdots$ stopping before $2m-4k-1$ is less than $m-1$

Comment: For $m=4$, both Donald Splutterwit's and my answers give $31$, but your answer gives $34$. Expanding $\left(1+x+x^2+x^3\right)^4=1+4x+10x^2+20x^3+31x^4+\dots$ seems to agree with those answers.

Comment: @robjohn 31 is correct. I have found my error.

Comment: Did you mean to say roll an $m$ on $m$ $4$-sided dice?

Comment: You still have an extra "on $m$" in your first sentence.

Answer (score 2):

$$
\begin{align}
\left[x^m\right]\left(\frac{\color{#C00}{1-x^4}}{\color{#090}{1-x}}\right)^m
&=\left[x^m\right]\left(\color{#C00}{\sum_{k=0}^m\binom{m}{k}(-1)^kx^{4k}}\color{#090}{\sum_{j=0}^\infty\binom{-m}{j}(-1)^jx^j}\right)\tag1\\
&=\sum_{k=0}^{\lfloor m/4\rfloor}(-1)^k\binom{m}{k}(-1)^{m-4k}\binom{-m}{m-4k}\tag2\\
&=\sum_{k=0}^{\lfloor m/4\rfloor}(-1)^k\binom{m}{k}\binom{2m-4k-1}{m-4k}\tag3
\end{align}
$$
Explanation:
$(1)$: Use the Binomial Theorem on the numerator and denominator
$(2)$: we want the coefficients of the terms with exponent $4k+j=m$
$(3)$: $\binom{-n}{k}=(-1)^k\binom{n+k-1}{k}$

Applying $(3)$ to $m=\{0,1,2,3,4,5,6,\dots\}$ gives $\{1,1,3,10,31,101,336\dots\}$

---

Note that in $(3)$, we could use $\binom{2m-4k-1}{m-4k}=\binom{2m-4k-1}{m-1}$, which might simplify things a bit, but that doesn't work for $m=0$.

Comment: \begin{eqnarray*}
\frac{1}{(1-x)^m} = \sum_{j=0}^{\infty} \binom{m+j-1}{j} x^j 
\end{eqnarray*}
and $4k+j=m$ ... would have made it slightly easier to follow. Anyway yours is the best solution.

Comment: @DonaldSplutterwit: Thanks. I have added more explanation. Hopefully, that helps.

Comment: Yeah it was $(3):$ that I did not get immediately. $\color{red}{\text{Neat}}$ use of $\color{green}{\text{colour}}$ $\ddot \smile$

Answer (score 0):

hint: [multinomial theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multinomial_theorem) might be a help.

Comment: I had looked up your given link. It's nice but gives nothing about how could I enumerate the number of ways to decompose given $m$ using only $0,1,2,3$

Comment: I guess I don't get the question I thought you were asking about what the coefficient of $x^m$ was etc. maybe look up [compositions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_(combinatorics)).

Answer (score 0):

An alternative approach would be to calculate the $m^{th}$ derivative at $x=0$. By the taylor series you will obtain the coefficient if you devide the  $m^{th}$ derivative at $x=0$ by $m!$.